# Prove that $C_p[-\pi,\pi]$ is complete, knowing that $C[-\pi,\pi]$ is indeed complete

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, complete-spaces, sequence-of-function

Show that the space
$$C_p[-\pi,\pi] = \{f \in C[-\pi,\pi] \; | \; f(-\pi)=f(\pi) \}$$
is complete knowing that the space $C[-\pi,\pi]$, i.e. continuous functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$, is complete.

Here is my proof.

$C[-\pi,\pi]$ is complete wrt the supremum norm
$$\|f\| = \sup_{t \in [-\pi,\pi]}|f(t)|,$$
and $C_p[-\pi,\pi] \subset C[-\pi,\pi]$. Therefore, taking a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $C_p[-\pi,\pi]$, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = f_0 \in C[-\pi,\pi].$$
Now it's just left to prove that $f_0(-\pi)=f_0(\pi)$. In order to do that, we know that the convergence with respect to the supremum norm implies uniform convergence $f_n \to f_0$, which, in turn, implies pointwise convergence $f_n(x) \to f_0(x), \; \forall x \in [-\pi,\pi]$. Therefore, we can write
$$\begin{cases} \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(-\pi) = f_0(-\pi), \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(\pi) = f_0(\pi).  \end{cases}$$
Substracting
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(-\pi) - \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(\pi) = f_0(-\pi)-f_0(\pi) \\ \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}(f_n(-\pi)-f_n(\pi)) = f_0(-\pi)-f_0(\pi).$$
Now we use that $(f_n)$ is in $C_p[-\pi,\pi]$, therefore $f_j(-\pi)=f_j(\pi) \; \forall j \in \mathbb{N}.$ Hence by calling
$$(a_n) = (f_n(-\pi)-f_n(\pi)) \; \forall \; n \in \mathbb{N} \quad \text{and} \quad a_0 = f_0(-\pi)-f_0(\pi)\\
\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a_0,$$
but $(a_n)$ is a sequence of zeros and therefore:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a_0 = 0$$

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Whether my proof is good or not

Comment: It is correct. However you could probably argue that $f_0(\pi)=f_0(-\pi)$  in a simpler manner. Simply note that $(f_n(\pi))_{\mathbb N}$ and $(f_n(-\pi))_{\mathbb N} $ are exactly the same sequence, so their limits are the same.

Comment: $C_p$ is the null space of the continuous linear functional $\Phi(f)=f(\pi)-f(-\pi)$. A closed subspace of a complete space is complete.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I am not at that level yet, but thank you for the insight!